# How can I get remote clients to approve colours without sending them prints?

Tags: color, client-relations, color-reproduction

A remote client needs to approve of some colours I chose.

I am wondering if there are any new solutions to this problem that doesn’t involve sending prints in the post?

Comment: What do you mean "that don't involve sending thing in the post?"

Comment: ermm...a web link? If you mean *physical color samples*, I think post is the *only* solution. Nothing RGB is going to be an exact match to a physical sample. Even sending a  link to a PDF will rely heavily on a viewers monitor color profiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory you should be able to send a print ready PDF to a print shop near the client and make them print a certified approval which simulates the color profile of the print shop where you are going to make the actual print. The client would have to pick up that print in person though. But since you don't see the physical approval yourself and it's not handed over to the print shop doing the job (which would require sending it in the post), it's all pretty risky.

Another possibility is to have the client look at the PDF on a color calibrated monitor and somehow make sure it's soft proofed with the right CMYK profile. The client should also be accustomed to viewing print PDFs on screen because even under the best possible conditions it still takes a little imagination to fully understand how it will look on print.

You could perhaps restrict yourself to using colors shown in some standard CMYK color book (from Pantone for example). That would require you, the client and the print shop to have the same color book. I don't think I would recommend this option as color books actually vary a bit and the print shop might not be able to guarantee total likeness as they might print using a different standard than the color book was made with.

If none of these options are possible, the client will just have to live with a slightly wrong preview and trust you to have chosen some nice looking colors.